# Is there any way to find names of uploaded files and downloaded files from my computer

Tags: internet, desktop-computer

Is there any way to find names of **uploaded files** and **downloaded files** from my computer is there any place in computer where computer logs history of uploaded and downloaded files?
i am using window 8.1

Comment: No. Upload/download is performed by some application/executable, not by computer - look for its logs. If no than no...

Comment: Uploaded/downloaded with what protocol(s)? What local server(s)/client(s)? Please [edit] the question. Note it should be specific. Broad questions will be closed. Please see [ask].

Comment: You can use the same folder for uploads and downloads and set your browsers to use that folder.  "Downloads" may have already been set up. Use that folder and then the files and their names will be there.

Comment: Some browsers like Chrome keep records of downloads you did using that browser.